# Realm triggers migration exception after fresh install

Tags: ios, realm

I'm struggling with a strange behavior of Realm database.

The issue that I experience:
1. I have a local default.realm schema file where I added a field into one of structures.
2. Taking into account that there is no versions in production I don't implement any migration block and expect that after deleting and installing mobile application Realm works.

But, after attempts of using Realm I get the InvalidSchemaVersionException and message in console:  "Provided schema version 0 is less than last set version 1." 
(I  use "defaultConfiguration" as a config.)

I know that it's possible to set deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded and it will work but it's not very convenient when I distribute builds among a few devices for testing etc.

I tried all simple actions as cleaning derived data folder, clean product folder in Xcode  etc.

So It seems that Realm in some way retrieves the previous schema (or it's version) from unknown for me location. How can I manually clean project or environment to make it work?

My environment:

Realm framework version: 3.15.0

Realm Object Server version: 3.26.1

Xcode version: 10.14.5

iOS/OSX version: 12.4.1

Dependency manager + version: CocoaPods, 1.6.1

Comment: Are you asking where the Realm files are actually stored on disk so you can delete them? If so, it depends on if you have sandboxing turned on or not. Update the question.

Comment: what do you mean by sandboxing? For iOS sandboxing is always on. If you mean capabilities, the app has app groups for extensions. Also there is iCloud key-value storage (I'm not sure it is's used by Realm) and Keychain sharing

Comment: by the way, I noticed that the issue happens also without changes to Realm structure. For example I created a configuration with deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded to fix the problem for a while. Next time I deleted and installed the app, the issue happened again.  It may be related to that before starting the app first time I copy a default.realm file from my bundle. Is it possible that the file itself contains a version?

Comment: Whoops. I do mostly macOS development so the sandboxing comment was for macOS. You're doing iOS so please ignore. Questions: you are bundling a populated Realm with your app for distribution? You mention copying a default.realm from your bundle *before the app starts*. If that happens before the app starts, what's that process look like? Also, did you ever have a migration block or do this `Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config` where the config was something other than the default?